# Experience with RabbitMQ/ AMQP on Openwhisk

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, openwhisk

does anyone of you have some experience using OpenWhisk together with an AMQP feed? I have a RabbitMQ infrastructure with multiple queues and events which should feed into Openwhisk triggers and execute my docker containers.

Sadly I did not found much on the Internet about OpenWhisk in connection with AMQP/RabbitMQ

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example feed provider for AMQP brokers has recently been published:

https://github.com/cliffjansen/amqp-wsk-feed

This is an open-source feed provider and not currently included in the core platform. You will have to manage and run the feed provider service to use this functionality.

Another option would be to enable the webhooks plugin for RabbitMQ: https://github.com/jbrisbin/rabbitmq-webhooks

Webhooks could be configured to invoke Web Actions on the platform.